# Android back button on media controller for videos played from webView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I am displaying a video in a webView and I am noticing particular behaviors from Kindle devices. First, you have to slide out the device buttons (on Kindle Fire HD), which brings up the video controls for the video. Pressing the back button while the controls are up will first hide the video controls. And then you have to press the back button again to dismiss the view. I have been trying to dismiss the view on first back press even while controls are up. The conflict I am running into is that I cannot capture that first back button press while the controls are up. Once the controls are gone and I press the back button it shows up in my @Override onBackPressed() OR the below dispatchKeyEvent() I added to try and resolve this issue.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // TODO
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Pressing the back button twice (after controls are gone) will register the keyEvent. But you still have to press it twice. Has anyone else ran into this conflict and/or do you know of a fix? I added both the dispatchkeyEvent() and onBackPressed() because I was hoping the dispatchKeyEvent() would catch the first back press, and then onBackPressed() would catch the second OR dispatchKeyEvent() would catch both. I get nothing while the controls are up for the first back press. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried removing `finish()`? What does `finish()` do?

Comment: If I remove finish(), I am unable to close the view at all even if onBackPressed is there. It seems that dispatchKeyEvent takes precedence over onBackPressed because dispatchKeyEvent will catch all back button presses. Without finish, nothing happens. I need to finish twice somehow it seems like

Comment: Are you sure it's not `ACTION_UP`?

Comment: Brilliant! You are on to something. The action on the first back button is actually action = 1. The second time you press now that the controller is gone, the action becomes down. This information allows me to finish() twice.

Comment: Yes! This works. Write up an answer. Say that I need to check for action = 1 and finish() on this action. And also check for normal action which is action = down and finish() that action. That solves whole conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_DOWN` will provide you with the next available child action in the hierarchy. However, I think you meant `ACTION_UP`, which takes you to the parent screen. You should also try putting `finish()` before the `if` statement.